# Fastest way to make holes (clearing circles) in texture

Tags: libgdx

I'm making a game which has changeable graphics. I have large pixmap and I'm making texture out of it which I'm rendering on screen. And that works well, except that every time I want to change texture I'm actually updating the pixmap and making texture out of it and it's super slow. Those holes are made by explosions and sometime I have like 20 explosions in short period of time and lag is noticeable.

So, I'm drawing empty circle in my pixmap and then I'm making new texture out of changed pixmap and destroying old texture.

Is there a faster way to change a texture? I don't see that texture class has some drawing functions at all?

Can I somehow draw a hole (empty circle) in texture directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both guys, but I was searching for easiest solution possible (that's why I'm libGDX anyway).

@Fuat, It's true, I don't have create new texture for every drawing (hole), but creating and destroying texture is not that expensive operation. Most expensive is moving whole pixmap to texture (large area). My solution that gives me excellent results and it's pretty easy is:

1. I'm drawing a hole (circle) at large pixmap as before.
2. I'm creating a temporary small pixmap, large enough just to take size of explosion (hole).
3. I'm copying part that was changed by hole drawing from large pixmap to small temporary one.
4. I'm drawing small pixmap to texture - much, much faster than drawing original, large texture. That's the crucial thing. Copying large pixmap to texture even without creating texutre again is most expesive operation. With small pixmap it's different story.
5. Disposing temporary pixmap.

And it works perfectly smooth now! Thanks for ideas anyway.
Hope, this will help someone too.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you applied seems ok but I think you don't need create new texture and destroy old one. There is a good tutorial here about modifying textures using pixmap :

http://blog.gemserk.com/2012/01/04/modifying-textures-using-libgdx-pixmap-in-runtime-explained/

They implemented a [PixmapHelper](https://github.com/gemserk/angryships/blob/c497c2786594380dd195096a2af521e98566526a/angryships-core/src/main/java/com/gemserk/prototypes/pixmap/PixmapHelper.java) class that modifies pixmap by putting hole's on it calling "fillCircle" method of Pixmap as you want.

Texture has been created in constructor using Pixmap and not refreshed with any new Pixmap data after erasing circular areas.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FrameBuffer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html) class for drawing to a texture quickly. You instantiate it with the texture dimensions you want. To draw to it, call `frameBuffer.begin()`, then optionally `gl.glClear(/*...*/);`, and then draw to it as you would normally draw to the screen, finishing with a call to `frameBuffer.end()`. To use the texture, use `frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()`.